# Deploy .net assembly from AOS to each client in AX2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Once a week I get the new version of .net assembly which I need to deploy to our Axapta 2012 installation. I don't want to copy this dll to axapta client folder on each computer.  So I am searching the way to deploy it to AOS and hope it will deploy on each client automatically.

I have found many solution (this is [one of them](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/09/ax-2012-net-assembly-deployment.html)), but all of them works only if I have the source code of this assembly. I don't have.  And I can not to 'Add VS project to AOT' and deploy it using VS add-ins.

Is there any way to deploy .net assembly (as compiled DLL) from AOS to each client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot do it using the "Add VS projection to AOT" method, you can use the `SysFileDeployment` class. This is demonstrated in Joris DG his blogpost [here](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2013/07/auto-deploying-dlls-and-other-resources_31.html).

On [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sysfiledeployment.aspx) the description of the `SysFileDeployment`class is as follows:
*The SysFileDeployment class is used for deploying files from the server to the clients.*

On msdn it is also explained how you need to do this.Basically all you need to do is extend this class and point to the files you need to deploy (in your case a dll). You will also have to change the build number of you solution to trigger the deployment.

You can also deploy dll's by adding them to the GAC, as demonstrated here:
[Axilicious: AX2012 DLL Deployment and how AX binds DLL’s at runtime](http://www.ksaelen.be/wordpresses/dynamicsaxblog/2013/05/ax2012-dll-deployment-and-how-ax-binds-dlls-at-runtime/)

To summarize main differences are:

- Using the visual studio properties: it is deployed to a folder specific to that user (so a different folder for each user) at the moment it is needed
- Using SysFileDeployment: it is copied to the client bin folder, a restart of the client is needed (possibly problems when on citrix/terminal services, like Joris suggests in the link you provided?)
- GAC: DLL's are stored in the Global Assembly Cache and different versions are stored but you need to provide a mechanism of deploying them yourself

Personally I would try the SysFileDeployment method as it's the standard method MS provide. If you have trouble, you might receive support.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a possible solution. If I understood correctly this class copy DLL after Axapta starts. It is not perfect as the users must restart client to use new version of DLL. Second I am not sure that user have access to write something to Axapta client directory. But anyway, than you very much!

Comment: When you deploy a new dll in a production environment, you'll have restarted the aos too so the clients will have to be restarted anyway. I'm sure the framework will have the permissions covered so I wouldn't worry about that. 
I've updated my answer so it also includes a link to an alternative way of deploying, using the GAC.